# Generator comprehension ignoring class scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I seem to be unsure as to how Python deals with variable scope in classes. This simple class demonstrates my issue:

```
x = 5  # Outside class scope
class SomeClass:
    x = 17  # Inside class scope

    # Generator expression should use x = 17 from inside class scope
    y = (x for i in range(10))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list(SomeClass.y)
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Apparently, the generator expression ignored the `x = 17` from inside the class. So, I thought I would change it to a list comprehension:

```
x = 5  # Outside class scope
class SomeClass:
    x = 17  # Inside class scope

    # List expression should use x = 17 from inside class scope
    y = [x for i in range(10)]
```

**Output (Python 2.x):**

```
>>> SomeClass.y
[17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]
```

In Python 2.x, list comprehensions seem to use the class's scope. However, this is not true in Python 3.x:

**Output (Python 3.x):**

```
>>> SomeClass.y
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

If I am to use Python 3.x, how do I use the class's variable scope? Both generator and list comprehensions seem to fail in using the class scope.

Comment: Is there a way to use the inner scope or will Python not allow it at all

Comment: This won't work, because `list` comprehensions and generator expressions create a function scope. So just like in a method, you can't access variables in the class body without referencing them using the class namespace, but the class namespace *does not exist yet* when you are using the comprehension. This worked in Python 2 because list-comprehensions were implemented differently, leading to "leaky" scope. This was fixed later. Note, other comprehension constructs never worked that way